# MeteorJS counting how many same data exists in the collection

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a collection that has 3 fields and each field has number '1' as data in it. I want to count the how many '1' exist in the collection in all 3 fields. I have the code like this:

```
return collection.find({}, {fields: {f1:1, f2:1, f3:1}}).count();
```

It should return 3 since there are only 3 '1' in the collection but it returned 10. I am not sure why, please help.

Comment: Currently I am doing the manual way:

`var f1 = collection.find({f1:'1'}).count();
var f2 = collection.find({f2:'1'}).count();
var f3 = collection.find({f3:'1'}).count();
return f1+f2+f3;`

to get the exact result.

Comment: "I want to count the how many '1' exist in the collection in all 3 fields." you mean fields or documents with all that three fields set to 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you trying to find if there is a 1 in ANY of the fields, or a 1 in ALL 3 fields? 
You said 1 in all fields, and Michel's answer would therefore be the correct one.

if you want 1 in ANY of the 3 fields, you want

`return collection.find({$or: [{f1:1}, {f2:1}, {f3:1}]}).count();`

Comment: It sorted out, I got the code like this:

`collection.find({$or: [{f1:'1'}, {f2:'1'}, {f3:'1'}]}).count();`

A combination of your answer and Michael Floyd's answer about putting a quote. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning the 3 fields instead of testing their values. Try:

```
return collection.find({f1:1, f2:1, f3:1}).count();
```

Comment: Are the data numbers or strings? If strings then quote the `"1"`s